# Various Errors in my Magento 2.4.5-p1

Tags: error

```
Magento 2.4.5-p1
Smartwave Porto
```

I have been developing a new Magento site via a fresh install. What I have done is Export products and customers from Magento 2.4.2-p1 and imported them into this new Magento 2.4.5-p1 site. I also upgraded this Magento from I believe 2.4.x to 2.4.5-p1 via the upgrade process. I only installed 1 calendar extension from Amasty and the multi-step checkout from Webkul.

Now when just working in categories and in Content -> Pages I run into these problems:

**1**. At random times - the following Error (*or similar*) comes up. It used to continue into the desired page in a couple of seconds but the last time, it just stayed on and I had to hit the Refresh button on the browser. **This also happens on the front end**:

This site can’t be reachedThe web page at https://MYSITE/new/catalog/category/delete/id/293/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

**2**. These Errors come up randomly when working in Categories or in Content -> Pages:

```
Something went wrong when loading Page in Content.

A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.
```

3. Sometimes, when saving pages (for example in Content -> Pages or when Saving a Category) - the circle going around just stays on and it says: Please wait... and never goes away...

**I have top-of-the-line hardware (many more resources than needed). Why is this happening and how to fix it?**